# How do I create a collection of functions?

Tags: design-patterns, f#, functional-programming, currying

I just want to say "usd_to_euro 100" and get back the correct amount of euros (ex: 90) for my particular day. What does create_exchange_functions need to return?

```
let create_exchange_functions (usd_to_euro_rate, usd_to_yuan_rate, usd_to_peso_rate, usd_to_pound_rate, usd_to_ruble_rate) = 
    (??, ??, ??, ....??);
```

//on the morning of day x I run this:

```
let (usd_to_euro, usd_to_yuan, usd_to_peso, usd_to_pound, usd_to_ruble) = create_exchange_functions(0.9, 4., 3., 0.6, 5.);
usd_to_pound 10.;
```

//on the morning of day y I run this:

```
let (usd_to_euro, usd_to_yuan, usd_to_peso, usd_to_pound, usd_to_ruble) = create_exchange_functions(0.92, 3.8, 3., 0.65, 5.);
usd_to_pound 10.;
```

//on the morning of day z I run this:

```
let (usd_to_euro, usd_to_yuan, usd_to_peso, usd_to_pound, usd_to_ruble) = create_exchange_functions(0.92, 3.8, 3., 0.62, 5.);
usd_to_pound 10.;
```

Comment: why mess this up in huge tuples? - Obviously you can do it for one rate like `let inline exchange rate input = input * rate` and then map a list of exchange-rates into a list of exchange functions with `let exchangeFuns = rates |> List.map exchange`

Comment: also this can be very readable and very *safe* if you use units-of-measure

Comment: I'm trying to mess around with the language with out using list functions. Trying to get a better understanding of the more basic.

Comment: Are you using F# Interactive or writing code and compiling? If you are trying to learn at the most basic level and avoid using list, then use F# Interactive to create a few functions and mess around with them quickly using F# Interactive.

Comment: Interactive on visual Studios. Its helping I am trying to approach this using pattern matching. I have almost figured it out, but help is always welcome.

Comment: @fractal , Your issue has been resolved?

Comment: Yes sorry. I got a bit busy. This is great. Thanks @GuyCoder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
let create_exchange_functions (usd_to_euro_rate, usd_to_yuan_rate, usd_to_peso_rate, usd_to_pound_rate, usd_to_ruble_rate) = 
(??, ??, ??, ....??);
```

how does one make this work.

Lets make this simpler for one item first and then we will do all of them.

```
let create_exchange_functions usd_to_euro_rate = 
    let toEuro dollar = usd_to_euro_rate * dollar
    toEuro
```

The key to understanding what you want is that you want a function that returns a new function which takes a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) value. Specifically for this example a curried parameter is a parameter a function needs but is not given when the function is created.

To see this add the types to `create_exchange_functions`

```
let create_exchange_functions (usd_to_euro_rate : float) : (float -> float) = 
    let toEuro dollar = usd_to_euro_rate * dollar
   toEuro
```

and we see that `create_exchange_functions` takes in a value `usd_to_euro_rate` and returns a function `(float -> float)` which is what we want.

But notice that when we created the function `toEuro` we only gave it the value for `usd_to_euro_rate` and not the value for `dollar`. This is what currying is doing. It is allowing us to create function that needs a parameter and the parameter can be supplied latter. So lets see how this is done.

Fist create the function `usd_to_eruo` using `create_exchange_functions`

```
let usd_to_euro = create_exchange_functions 0.9
```

and notice the signature of `usd_to_euro` is

```
val usd_to_euro : (float -> float)
```

So if we give it one float value it will give us back another float value.
The value we give it is a value for dollar

```
let dollar = 10.0
```

and we use it like

```
let euro = usd_to_euro dollar
printfn "Dollar: %A to Euro: %A" dollar euro
```

which gives

```
Dollar: 10.0 to Euro: 9.0
```

which is what we want.

Now to do it for all of the exchange rates

```
let create_exchange_functions (usd_to_euro_rate, usd_to_yuan_rate, usd_to_peso_rate, usd_to_pound_rate, usd_to_ruble_rate) = 
    let toEuro dollar = usd_to_euro_rate * dollar
    let toYuan dollar = usd_to_yuan_rate * dollar
    let toPeso dollar = usd_to_peso_rate * dollar
    let toPound dollar = usd_to_pound_rate * dollar
    let toRuble dollar = usd_to_ruble_rate * dollar
    (toEuro, toYuan, toPeso, toPound, toRuble)

let (usd_to_euro, usd_to_yuan, usd_to_peso, usd_to_pound, usd_to_ruble) = 
    create_exchange_functions(0.9, 4., 3., 0.6, 5.)

let dollar = 10.0
let pound = usd_to_pound dollar
printfn "Monday - Dollar: %A to Pound: %A" dollar pound

Monday - Dollar: 10.0 to Pound: 6.0

let (usd_to_euro, usd_to_yuan, usd_to_peso, usd_to_pound, usd_to_ruble) = 
    create_exchange_functions(0.92, 3.8, 3., 0.65, 5.)

let pound = usd_to_pound dollar
printfn "Tuesday - Dollar: %A to Pound: %A" dollar pound

Tuesday - Dollar: 10.0 to Pound: 6.5
```

Comment: Also take a look at [Partial Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application)